# Photo size limit for posting in twitter using Twitter SDK in Android

Tags: android, image, twitter4j

What is the size limit of the photo for posting I twitter using Twitter SDK in Android

Answer (score 0):

You can view your file size limit by hitting the configuration endpoint (requires authentication): https://api.twitter.com/1.1/help/configuration.json

I'm not sure if it can be changed but the limit is currently 3 mebibytes (3145728 bytes).